# Limiting amount of objects user can add in another object

Tags: python, django, model

I just have a quick question,
I would like to limit exercises in training unit to 3-5 exercises , and limit trianing units in trainingplan to 12 training units, so the user will not add an infinite ammount of exercises,or infinite amount of training units in a plan?

```
class TrainingPlan(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nameoftheplan = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name of the plan",max_length=20, null=True)
    Squat1RM = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="100%RM in squat",default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    DeadliftT1RM =models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="100%RM maximal repetition in deadlift",default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    Benchpress1RM = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="100%RM maximal repetition in benchpress",default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    mesocycle= models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MESOCYCLE_CHOICES,default=MESOCYCLE_GPP)
    timeoftheplan= models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=TIME_CHOICE,default=TIME_WEEK3 )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nameoftheplan)

class TrainingUnit(models.Model):
    trainingplan=models.ForeignKey(TrainingPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  

class Exercise(models.Model):
    trainingunit=models.ForeignKey(TrainingUnit,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exercisename=models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="Exercise",choices=EXERCISE_CHOICES)
    exercisesets=models.IntegerField(choices=SETSCHOICES)
    exercisereps=models.IntegerField(choices=REPCHOICES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you handle the user post request you can use `objects.filter().count()` or `objects.all().count()` the idea in `count()` you can apply it on any query you want, in this way you will check how many value you have in database based on condition after that you can **accept user post request or rias an error**